# Scrape and store Shopify ecommerce websites using Node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, shopify

I wrote a code to scrape an array of Shopify ecommerce websites using website-**scraper** npm module in node.js but it is showing 403 error but the same code is working for other websites.

How can we get around this problem?

My scraperTest.js file is :

```
var scrape = require('website-scraper');
let test = require('./test')
let urls = [];
urlList = ['1500.academy'];
urlList.forEach(url =>{
    test.checkRedirect(url)
    .then(domain =>{
        urls.push('https://' + domain);
        console.log(urls);
        var options = {
            urls: urls,
            directory: './autochat/',
            'User-Agent': 'request',
        };

        // with promise
        scrape(options).then((result) => {
            /* some code here */
        }).catch((err) => {
            /* some code here */
        });

        // or with callback
        scrape(options, (error, result) => {
            /* some code here */
        });
    })
})
```

and test.js file is

```
const request = require('request');
const extractDomain = require('extract-domain');

//var link = 'oneplustwocase.com';

function checkRedirect(link) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var url = "http://" + link;
        var options = {
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'request'
            }
        };
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            let redirectedDomain = extractDomain(response.request.uri.href);
            if(response !== undefined){
                extractDomain(response.request.uri.href);
                if (response.statusCode === 200 && link !== redirectedDomain) {
                   resolve(redirectedDomain);
                } else {
                    resolve(link);
                }
            } else {
                resolve(link);
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports.checkRedirect = checkRedirect;
```

Comment: I appreciate the audacity of the question. Reality is - there's all sorts of reasons and ways that Shopify might reject your requests and just return you a 403 without telling you why.

Comment: Is there any way to get over this problem. Like bluffing that the request is coming from a browser. I tried to use User Agent header but that too is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.
We are able to fetch the html data of the domain using request();
The response.body contains the html data

the solution I got by using the following code :

```
const request = require('request');
const extractDomain = require('extract-domain');
let fs = require('fs');

function checkRedirect(link) {
        var url = "http://" + link;
        var options = {
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'request'
            }
        };
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {

            if(response !== undefined){
                let redirectedDomain = extractDomain(response.request.uri.href);
                let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(redirectedDomain + '.html');
                writeStream.write(response.body)
                writeStream.end();
        });
}

module.exports.checkRedirect = checkRedirect;

//checkRedirect('oneplustwocase.com')

/*
var r = request(url, function (e, resp) {
    r.uri
    resp.request.uri
  })*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in data, save yourself the headache of scraping and simply download the site XML file. It contains all the products and interesting information, just like Google or any other search engine.

Answer (score 0):

- It seems that website http://1500.academy returns 403 if it doesn't like user-agent header. I suggest to try user-agent which looks like browser
- According to `website-scraper` documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/website-scraper#request you should pass headers for request in `request` property, not on root level

So options should be like:

```
const options = {
  urls:[{url: 'http://1500.academy/'}],
  directory: './autochat/',
  request: {
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',
    }
  }
}
```

By the way `website-scraper` follows redirects by default, so you can skip checking redirects